# Serialized data issue in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, serializearray

I am facing an issue in wordpress serialized data. I am developing a custom plugin which is in relation with woocommerce. I have added a checkout section in woocommerce settings section. Also I am providing same settings update form in my plugin section which is new menu option in left menu.

when I am saving data through woocommerce setting section it stores data in in wp_options table as serialized data. Below is example :

> a:18:{s:7:"enabled";s:3:"yes";s:9:"test_mode";s:2:"no";s:19:"is_application_name";s:0:"";s:10:"is_api_key";s:0:"";s:17:"order_customtable";s:0:"";s:16:"order_customflds";s:0:"";s:23:"order_product_customfld";s:0:"";s:14:"is_merchant_id";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:12:"Infusionsoft";s:9:"tax_label";s:9:"Sales Tax";s:16:"is_free_shipping";s:2:"no";s:11:"description";s:20:"Pay via
>   Infusionsoft";s:5:"cards";s:16:"VISA
>   MASTERCARD";s:14:"wooorderstatus";s:0:"";s:14:"thanks_message";s:39:"Thank
>   you. Your order has been
>   received";s:5:"debug";s:2:"no";s:11:"debug_email";s:0:"";s:13:"http_post_key";s:0:"";}

From my plugin page, on form submit I am getting field values and creating an array as below :

> Array (
>       [enabled] => yes
>       [test_mode] => no
>       [is_application_name] => 
>       [is_api_key] => 
>       [order_customtable] => 
>       [order_customflds] => 
>       [order_product_customfld] => 
>       [is_merchant_id] => 
>       [title] => Infusionsoft
>       [tax_label] => Sales Tax
>       [is_free_shipping] => no
>       [description] => Pay via Infusionsoft
>       [cards] => VISA MASTERCARD
>       [wooorderstatus] => 
>       [thanks_message] => Thank you. Your order has been received
>       [debug] => no
>       [debug_email] => 
>       [http_post_key] =>  )

Now serializing and updating option using function update_option it will save data in in data base as below string :

> s:597:"a:18:{s:7:"enabled";s:3:"yes";s:9:"test_mode";s:2:"no";s:19:"is_application_name";s:0:"";s:10:"is_api_key";s:0:"";s:17:"order_customtable";s:0:"";s:16:"order_customflds";s:0:"";s:23:"order_product_customfld";s:0:"";s:14:"is_merchant_id";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:12:"Infusionsoft";s:9:"tax_label";s:9:"Sales Tax";s:16:"is_free_shipping";s:2:"no";s:11:"description";s:20:"Pay via
>   Infusionsoft";s:5:"cards";s:15:"VISA
>   MASTERCARD";s:14:"wooorderstatus";s:0:"";s:14:"thanks_message";s:39:"Thank
>   you. Your order has been
>   received";s:5:"debug";s:2:"no";s:11:"debug_email";s:0:"";s:13:"http_post_key";s:0:"";}";

Please help me in this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't serialize the array yourself, `update_option` will do it if needed.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/